# InfluxDB API. Records in which a given field is not empty

Tags: influxdb

I am using InfluxDB monitoring through a query API obtained from Grafana. I need to retrieve all records except the ones with the measurement "last" in NULL.

```
  SELECT last(usage_idle)  FROM "cpu" WHERE (host = 'myhost' AND cpu = 'cpu-total') AND time >= now() - 6h GROUP BY time(20s), "cpu" fill(null) limit 100
```

However the query keeps returning records with that empty measurement:

```
                {
                    "results": [
                        {
                            "statement_id": 0,
                            "series": [
                                {
                                    "name": "cpu",
                                    "tags": {
                                        "cpu": "cpu-total"
                                    },
                                    "columns": [
                                        "time",
                                        "last"
                                    ],
                                    "values": [
                                        [
                                            "2020-10-13T08:44:40Z",
                                            null
                                        ],
                                        [
                                            "2020-10-13T08:45:00Z",
                                            98.95878904
                                        ],
                                        [
                                            "2020-10-13T08:45:20Z",
                                            null
                                        ]
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
```

What syntax should be used in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you use a selector function such as **last** and **GROUP BY time(...)** clause, the influxdb will return **null** values within the grouped time intervals where no values have been found.

In this particular case a desired outcome could be achieved by reconstructing your main query into a subquery in the following way:

```
SELECT "last" FROM ( SELECT last(usage_idle)  FROM "cpu" WHERE (host = 'myhost' AND cpu = 'cpu-total') AND time >= now() - 6h GROUP BY time(20s), "cpu" fill(null) ) limit 100
```

Using test data and **Grafana Query Inspector** the following output is achieved with the modified query:

```
q:";SELECT "last" FROM ( SELECT last(usage_idle)  FROM "cpu" WHERE (host = 'myhost' AND cpu = 'cpu-total') AND time >= now() - 6h GROUP BY time(20s), "cpu" fill(null) ) limit 100 "
epoch:"ms"
data:null
precision:"ms"
hideFromInspector:false
response:Object
results:Array[1]
0:Object
statement_id:0
series:Array[1]
0:Object
name:"cpu"
columns:Array[2]
0:"time"
1:"last"
values:Array[2]
0:Array[1602794560000,98.95878904]
1:Array[1602798140000,99.95878904]
..
```

..versus the outcome using the original query that appeared as follows:

```
q:"SELECT last(usage_idle)  FROM "cpu" WHERE (host = 'myhost' AND cpu = 'cpu-total') AND time >= now() - 6h GROUP BY time(20s), "cpu" fill(null) limit 100"
epoch:"ms"
data:null
precision:"ms"
hideFromInspector:false
response:Object
results:Array[1]
0:Object
statement_id:0
series:Array[1]
0:Object
name:"cpu"
tags:Object
cpu:"cpu-total"
columns:Array[2]
0:"time"
1:"last"
values:Array[100]
0:Array[1602776660000,null]
1:Array[1602776680000,null]
2:Array[1602776700000,null]
3:Array[1602776720000,null]
4:Array[1602776740000,null]
...
```